# Building a shell in C on Ubuntu using execvp

Tags: c, linux

1. I'm about to write a simple shell in C on Ubuntu.
   I thought about using the `exevcp()` function.
   I'm only able to run the "ls" command, none of the other commands seems to work.
   Can someone tell me why is it happening or give me an idea of a better way to build the shell?
2. My purpose is to build this shell; I don't understand why can't I just take the command line, and put it as it is, into the `execvp()` function.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>

   #include <string.h>
   #include <errno.h>

   int main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)
   {
       char* args[] = {"history" , NULL};

       execvp(args[0],args);
   }
   ```

Can you explain to me, please?

Answer (score 3):

`exec(3)` can only be used to run external programs. `history` is a built-in in most shells, and cannot be run this way.

Comment: Um, first you write the implementation, and then you call it.

Answer (score 1):

The `execvp()` system call has two arguments: the name of the program to be executed, and a pointer to a null-terminated list of strings that are the arguments to the command.

For example:

```
char *args[] = { "ls", "-l", "-t", "-r", ".", 0 };
execvp(args[0], args);
...report error...
```

You can't simply pass a whole string into `execvp()` and expect it to split it up; the invoking code must do that.  Note that if string pointed at by the first argument to `execvp()` contains a slash, then the `$PATH` mechanism is not used to find the command.  A plain name (as shown, `"ls"`) is searched using `$PATH`.

You also have to remember that some commands, such as `history` and `cd`, are shell built-ins; there is no external executable that you can run to get the same effect  You won't be able to run those.  Other commands, such as `test` (aka `[`) are usually implemented as built-ins, but there's also usually a binary in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` that does (more or less) the same job, which you can therefore invoke.